# Warning: Unknown prop on <> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: reactjs, prop, subcomponent

I'm new to react and i was learning subclasses from one of Lynda examples. I'm creating a new subcomponent class called `aptList` and using `this.props.eachItem.ownerName` to iterate through each index from the JSON file where `ownerName` is a property.

This is the error i get when i run it in the browser. The data gets fetched but the `prop` is not getting recognized according to the error

[image: warning on console]

however the react console seems to be getting the JSON fine

[image: react console]

This is the code as taught on Lynda

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');

var aptList = createReactClass({
render: function(){
    return(
        <li>{ this.props.eachItem.ownerName }</li>
    );
}
});


var MainInterface = createReactClass({

   getInitialState: function(){
      return {
        title: 'Items',
        show: function(x){
            if(x>10){
                return true
            }
            else {
                return false
            }
        },
        myData: []
    }
},

componentDidMount: function(){

    this.serverRequest = $.getJSON('static/scripts/src/myData.json', function(results){
        var tempData = results;
        this.setState({
            myData: tempData
        });
    }.bind(this));
},


componentWillUnmount: function(){
    this.serverRequest.abort();
},

render: function(){

    var style = {
        color: 'red',
        fontWeight: 900
    };

    var reactData = this.state.myData;
    reactData = reactData.map(function (each, index) {
        return (
            <aptList eachItem = { each }
                     key = { index }/>
        )
    }.bind(this));

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{ this.state.show(12) ? 'List of ':null }{ this.state.title }</h1>
            <ul style={style}>
                { reactData }
            </ul>
        </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MainInterface/>,
    document.getElementById('testid')
);
```

Comment: It's an "industry standard" that component names are capitalised, otherwise react thinks that it's dealing with an HTML tag and checks for allowed attributes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rename `aptList` to `AptList`.

Otherwise React considers `aptList` to be a native html component and will trigger warnings for unknown HTML properties.

See the [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html) in the exception message:

> 4. You are using a React component without an upper case. React interprets it as a DOM tag because ...